# How to get a Ordereddictionary element with lowest value, which is also greater than a certian threshold, in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

Right now i am doing this to get the key for the lowest value in an ordered dict

```
hunting_targets = OrderedDict()
for element in data["hunting_targets"]:
    hunting_targets[data["hunting_targets"][element]["user_id"]]=data["hunting_targets"]element]["gold"]
hunting_targets=OrderedDict(sorted(hunting_targets.items(), key=lambda t: t[1],reverse= False))

hunting_target = next(iter(hunting_targets))
```

I would now repeat the last step until value is greater than Threshold.

But there is probably a more efficient way isn't there ?

What is a more efficient way of doing this?

Edit: key is and id of type int. and value is an int too

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the exact arrangement of your data (i.e. what are the keys and values of `data`, `hunting_targets`, etc.), it's difficult to be certain.  But you may see performance improvements by using a [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) in some fashion.  The heapq algorithm is designed to keep the smallest element of a collection readily available.